# Add Wordpress Blog Posts to AMP-HTML Page Without Plugin

Tags: amp-html

I want to add post excerpt and feature image of up to 4 Wordpress blog posts. I don't want to use an AMP plugin as there are some limitations with them and none of the plugins get it completely right. I also don't want to use an iFrame solution since it's pulling from the blog on the same domain.

I've tried researching and looking at AMP templates but I haven't been able to find any specific to Wordpress that don't just create the pages dynamically. i.e. I can't find example code

Unfortunately I have no code to show.

Does anyone have either the code needed to pull these posts or a suggested resource to determine how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I can help, but I need to better understand what you want with AMP technology. If you are creating the content amp display on your website.